# Wordpress Hosting Import Error Conflit Plugin Dokan

Tags: wordpress

I went to import the site from another Wordpress hosting, and it is giving this error. The files are in the folder even though they are not. And every part of the plugin doesn't work.
Everything seems to work except this plugin. But in the other hosting without touching anything it works normally.

```
me/u905569257/domains/smeh.com.br/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/libraries/class-emogrifier.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u905569257/domains/smeh.com.br/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dokan-pro/includes/admin/announcement-background-process.php on line 14

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home/u905569257/domains/smeh.com.br/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/libraries/class-emogrifier.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/u905569257/domains/smeh.com.br/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dokan-pro/includes/admin/announcement-background-process.php on line 14

Warning: include_once(/home/u905569257/domains/smeh.com.br/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dokan-pro/includes/modules/rma): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u905569257/domains/smeh.com.br/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dokan-pro/dokan-pro.php on line 286

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home/u905569257/domains/smeh.com.br/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dokan-pro/includes/modules/rma' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/u905569257/domains/smeh.com.br/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dokan-pro/dokan-pro.php on line 286
```